# how to position images by Javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three checkboxes, which are linked to three images (image dimensions, not that it matters: 800x500, 500x300, 290x170). I want those images like:

1)When three of them are clicked, two images should be beside each other, 290x170 should be under those two.

2)If first button is switched off, 290x170 should be on top and 500x300 on bottom.

3)If second button is switched off, on top should be 800x500 image and under that 290x170.

4)If third button is switched off, 800x500 and 500x300 images should be beside each other.

5)default should be 290x170 image.

```js
function checkValue() {
  let CheckBox1 = document.getElementById("CheckBox1");
  let CheckBox2 = document.getElementById("CheckBox2");
  let CheckBox3 = document.getElementById("CheckBox3");

  if (CheckBox1 && CheckBox2 && CheckBox3.checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("image1").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("image2").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("image3").style.display = "inline";
  } else if (CheckBox2 && CheckBox3.checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("image1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("image2").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("image3").style.display = "inline";
  } else if (CheckBox1 && CheckBox2.checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("image1").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("image2").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("image3").style.display = "none";
  } else CheckBox1 && CheckBox3.checked == true;
  document.getElementById("image1").style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById("image2").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("image3").style.display = "inline";
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <p>Choose dimensions for an image</p>
  <button class="btn">800x500
              <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" id="CheckBox1" onclick='checkValue()'>
                <span class="slider"></span>
              </label>
            </button>
  <button class="btn">500x300
              <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" id="CheckBox2" onclick='checkValue()'>
                <span class="slider"></span>
              </label>
            </button>
  <button class="btn">290x170
              <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" id="CheckBox3" onclick='checkValue()'>
                <span class="slider"></span>
              </label>
            </button>
</div>

<div id="main-content">
  <div class="image-boxes">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x500.jpg" id="image1" class="image" style="display:none" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300.jpg" id="image2" class="image" style="display:none" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/290x170" id="image3" class="image" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `CheckBox1 && CheckBox2 && CheckBox3.checked == true` won't do what you expect

Comment: `checked` is a state inside the condition itself. It does not need a boolean (true/false) afterward. Then it only checks if the `CheckBox3` is checked and ignores the rest for which a condition is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Inside every if check of yours, the conditional is not written correctly.

```
CheckBox1 && CheckBox2 && CheckBox3.checked == true
```

Is the same as just checking `CheckBox3.checked`. Because you are not checking the value of `.checked` property for the first 2 checkboxes, JS will check their truthy-ness. And because CheckBox1 and CheckBox2 exist (not null), they become true.
Also, `if` statements takes in a boolean value (true or false). Since the `.checked` value is already a boolean, there is no need to compare it to `true`.

Instead, the conditional should look like this. Same problem for the `else if`s.

```
if (CheckBox1.checked && CheckBox2.checked && CheckBox3.checked) {
...
```

Lastly, `else` should not take any condition, so it should be:

```
else{
  document.getElementById("image1").style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById("image2").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("image3").style.display = "inline";
}
```